# How do I rotate a face around an axis in normal orientation in Python?

Tags: python, normals, bmesh

I have a set of vertices for a `BMFace` that I'm trying to rotate around the x-axis but in the face's normal orientation. Currently I'm doing:

```
c = face.calc_center_median()
T = Matrix.Translation(-c)
rot_angle = 0.25
rot_axis = (1, 0, 0)
bmesh.ops.rotate(
    bm,
    space=T,
    matrix=Matrix.Rotation(rot_angle, 4, rot_axis),
    verts=face.verts
)
```

My guess is that I can get the normal x-axis through `face.normal` but I'm not sure what to do next or how to best formulate the question to learn more. There are an infinite number of possible x-axes orthogonal to `face.normal`, aren't there?

Answer (score 1):

After some reading I managed a solution, but I'm not sure how robust it is:

```
tangent = face.calc_tangent_edge_pair()
rot_axis = -face.normal.cross(tangent)
```

The tangent is one of the other normal axes and from that the last axis is calculated as its cross product with the face's normal.

This seems dependent on which edges are the longest ([the documentation for `BMFace.calc_tangent_edge_pair`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMFace.calc_tangent_edge_pair) says: "Return face tangent based on the two longest disconnected edges."), so I imagine there's a better way to approach this!